# Streams API: possible to undo .pipeTo()?

Tags: javascript, serial-port, whatwg-streams-api

The [Streams API](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) provides a neat way of piping a `ReadableStream` to a `WritableStream` using [`readableStream.pipeTo(writableStream)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeTo). This would appear to be more convenient than obtaining `readableStream.getReader()` and manually gluing it to `writableStream.getWriter()` or directly to underlying functionality.

I have a use case where I am provided a `ReadableStream` object which may eventually need to "go away" and be replaced by a new `ReadableStream` object. It would be nice to use a single custom `WritableStream` to wrap the functionality which these `ReadableStream` objects interface with and pipe them together for as long as needed, but have not found how to "undo" the piping process.

**Q: Is it possible to "undo"/"break"/"teardown" a pipe created with `.pipeTo()`, or are pipes "permanent" and not appropriate for this use case?**

Example using [Serial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/), where I would like to be able to call `doConnectPort()` and then `doDisconnectPort()` repeatedly:

```js
var customWritable = new WritableStream(…);
var port;

async function doConnectPort() {
  port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
  await port.open({ baudrate: …});
  await port.readable.pipeTo(customWritable);
}

async function doDisconnectPort() {
  // What to do here? Can't close the port yet—port.readable is still locked!
  await port.close();
}
```

Currently, I manually glue things together and clean up when it's time to disconnect the port:

```js
var port;
var portReader;

async function doConnectPort() {
  port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
  await port.open({ baudrate: …});
  portReader = port.readable.getReader();
  while (true) {
    const { value, done } = await portReader.read();
    if (done) {
      break;
    }
    // do something with value
  }
}

async function doDisconnectPort() {
  await portReader.cancel();
  await portReader.releaseLock();
  await port.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an [AbortSignal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) in the `pipeTo`'s option object's `signal`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector( "button" );
const checkbox = document.querySelector( "input" );

if( !ReadableStream.prototype.pipeTo ) {
  console.warn( "Your browser doesn't support pipeTo" );
}
else {

btn.onclick = (evt) => {

  console.clear( "" );
  const blob = new Blob( [ "hello" ] );
  const readable = blob.stream();
  const target = new TransformStream();
  const abort_controller = new AbortController();

  target.readable.getReader().read().then( console.log );

  readable.pipeTo( target.writable, { signal: abort_controller.signal } )
    .catch( console.error )

  if( checkbox.checked ) {
    abort_controller.abort();
  }
  
};

}
```

```html
<label>Abort pipe<input type="checkbox" checked></label><br>
<button id="btn">new test</button>
```

Comment: I had asked [WHATWG Streams' GitHub page](https://github.com/whatwg/streams/issues/1055) and received similar answers (and hadn't yet shared here). I have verified that this approach works for the Serial API use case.